# Avoid cross-region call on RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am working with a web application that uses AWS RDS database, currently,  It is available only on India(Mumbai origin), form now, I want to make it available for multiple regions(US-Ohio and Mumbai both). In that case, is there any possibility to configure my RDS for below scenarios

The request comes from US-Ohio it severs by RDS instance from Ohio region and the request comes from India then data will server by RDS instance from Mumbai region and both RDS instance replicate each other means both instance act as single DB

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

A typical (single-server) database keeps all information in one location (eg Mumbai).

You could add a **read replica** in another region (eg Ohio). This would replicate information to Ohio, but the replica in Ohio could only be used for **querying** (reading) data. All updates would need to be made to the primary database in Mumbai. This makes querying faster without needing "multiple masters".

From [Working with Amazon Aurora Global Database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html):

> An **Aurora global database** consists of one primary AWS Region where your data is mastered, and up to five read-only, secondary AWS Regions. Aurora replicates data to the secondary AWS Region with typical latency of under a second. You issue write operations directly to the primary DB instance in the primary AWS Region. An Aurora global database uses dedicated infrastructure to replicate your data, leaving database resources available entirely to serve application workloads. Applications with a worldwide footprint can use reader instances in the secondary AWS Regions for low latency reads. In the unlikely event your database becomes degraded or isolated in an AWS region, you can promote one of the secondary AWS Regions to take full read-write workloads in under a minute.
>
> The Aurora cluster in the primary AWS Region where your data is mastered performs both read and write operations. The cluster in the secondary region enables low-latency reads. You can scale up the secondary clusters independently by adding one of more DB instances (Aurora Replicas) to serve read-only workloads. For disaster recovery, you can remove and promote one of the secondary clusters to allow full read and write operations.

Going one step further, you could [Work with Amazon Aurora Multi-Master Clusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html) where all DB instances have read-write capability:

> In a **multi-master cluster**, all DB instances can perform write operations. The notions of a single read-write primary instance and multiple read-only Aurora Replicas don't apply. There isn't any failover when a writer DB instance becomes unavailable, because another writer DB instance is immediately available to take over the work of the failed instance. We refer to this type of availability as *continuous availability*, to distinguish it from the *high availability* (with brief downtime during failover) offered by a single-master cluster.

Each option is a trade-off between performance, cost and complexity. It is highly likely that a **Read Replica** or **Global Database** will be sufficient for your needs, because **most database operations are queries rather than updates**.

You should experiment with each option and run performance tests on your application to confirm that you are achieving your desired performance. Also, **review the associated costs** (which will likely double due to having multiple servers, plus there will be additional costs for Data Transfer between the two regions).

Also, please note that the above capabilities will differ depending upon the database engine you choose. (The above are for Amazon Aurora running MySQL.)

Comment: Can you please help me on what kind of configuration i have to add for reading will be made from Ohio region and update operation will made on  Master instance(Mumbai) region while request comes from Ohio region?

Comment: Which database engine are you using in Amazon RDS?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.22

Comment: It appears you are _not_ using Amazon Aurora. Therefore, Amazon RDS for MySQL can offer you **Read Replicas**. See: [Working with Read Replicas - Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) Basically, you would point _Read_ queries to the endpoint of the local Read Replica in Ohio. Any _Write_ queries (eg INSERT, UPDATE) should be sent to the endpoint of the master database in Ohio. Your application will need to be modified to connect to the appropriate endpoint based upon the query type being performed.